# Using StructureMap to scan for implementations exposed in external modules

Tags: structuremap, masstransit

I am trying to scan a folder of modules (dlls, location known at runtime) using StructureMap 2.6.4, for any that close a certain interface. In this case, it’s Consumes.Context from MassTransit.

My class, of which there may be many implementations of, in the modules folder:

```
    public class MyConsumer : Consumes<MyMessage>.Context
    {

        public void Consume(IConsumeContext< MyMessage > message)
        {
            // Do some stuff

            message.Respond(response);
        }
    }
```

My StructureMap scanner:

> ```
>         container.Configure(x => x.Scan(y =>
>         {
>             y.TheCallingAssembly();
>             y.WithDefaultConventions();
>             y.LookForRegistries();
>             y.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(Consumes<>.Context));
>             y.AddAllTypesOf(typeof(Consumes<>.Context));
>             y.AssembliesFromPath(@"..\..\..\Web\Modules\bin\debug");         
>         }));
> ```

When I look at what objects are in the container, I do not see any of my Consumes<>.Context implementations. I do see objects from other dlls in the debug folder.

However, if I copy my module’s dll into a sub-directory and scan like this:

```
y.AssembliesFromPath(@"..\..\..\Web\Modules\bin\debug\test")
```

The scanner picks up my objects.

Fails:

```
y.AssembliesFromPath(@"..\..\..\Web\Modules\bin\debug");
```

Works:

```
y.AssembliesFromPath(@"..\..\..\Web\Modules\bin\debug\test");
```

Why would placing my dll in a sub-directory work and not work in the parent directory?

How should I be scanning for implementations of Consumes.Context in a Modules directory?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever get a resolution on this?

Comment: Nope, I wish I had. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/structuremap-users/8icMlRi-Lzo